# how to detect first visit to site with cookies, and without cookies

Tags: php, cookies, visited

I am adding a "welcome loader" to a website.

I can detect if the visit is new or not with cookies:

```
function show_loader()
{
 setcookie("loader_shown", "1", time() + 80,"/"); 

 echo "<div class='loader'>hello</div>";    

}

if(! $_COOKIE['loader_shown'])
{
 die(show_loader());
}

// the rest of the code to show the site.......
```

all good for browsers with cookies enabled.... but how would I handle this situation for non cookie enabled browsers? Thinking about setting another cookie, then seeing if it is set before running this bit....

answers on a postcard!

Comment: you can't set/check cookies in a single page visit. You have to wait for the user to come back for hit #2 to see if they send the cookie back to you. most sites do this by setting the cookie, then forcing a reload of the page so hit #2 is triggered.

Comment: yes, thought that would be the case, do you think that "refresh" approach is the way to go? at the moment if the browser has cookies disabled it will effectively always show the loader, thus hiding the entire site..

Answer (score 2):

You could store the IP and user agent of the user on the server and do not show the message if the given IP/UA combination saw it recently.

If you just want to use cookies you'd have to do it like this (pseudocode-ish):

```
# page 1
if(isset($_COOKIE['welcome_shown'])) {
  redirect('home page')
  exit
}
setcookie('has_cookies', true)
redirect(page 2)

# page 2
if(isset($_COOKIE['has_cookies']) && !isset($_COOKIE['welcome_Shown'])) {
  show_welcome_message()
  setcookie('welcome_shown', true)
  exit
}
redirect('home page')
```

Comment: Indeed, but for a "welcome"-style page both false positives and false negatives are probably rather harmless

Comment: yes, the ip/user agent is a reasonable approach to solve the non cookie scenario, Hmm. This must be a problem that has been faced many times before, im suprised there are no more answers to this one!

Comment: ip + user agent seems good to me, but are there some variables to add to this check to work better?

Comment: localStorage in addition to a cookie. That will work for people who heard "cookies are eeeeeeeevil" but never disabled JS and/or LSO. However, you can only access it client-side and not on the server.